# local shopify app development with docker: Request origin could not be verified

Tags: docker, shopify, shopify-app, ngrok

So I have a dockerized shopify app (Node / React) which I want to improve. Naturally I would like to be able to make changes locally and test them in my local environment prior to publishing them to the stage environment.

I almost got my setup up and running, however once I install my locally running app in a shopify dev store I get the error: `Request origin could not be verified`

The reason for this is probably the callback url, which is: `https://shopify-app.local/auth/callback?...` and not the ngrok-url.

In my `ngrok.conf` I set the `host_header` to shopify-app.local:

```
web_addr: 0.0.0.0:4040
region: eu
authtoken: [MY_TOKEN]
log: stdout
tunnels:
  shopify-app:
    proto: http
    addr: https://shopify-app.local
    host_header: shopify-app.local
```

(This is necessary for the proxy to correctly distribute the traffic and that part is actually working - my app receives incoming traffic).

So I guess what I'm missing here is to set the appropriate host-header in the responses to the ngrok-generated url. But where and how would I do this?

I'm using the infamous [jwilder/nginx-proxy](https://hub.docker.com/r/jwilder/nginx-proxy)

For a better understanding, my setup looks like this:
[image: My Setup]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anybody stumbles upon this, the solution was as simple as adding `add_header  Host  [ngrok-address] always;` to the `location` directive in the nginx-configuration for the appropriate service.

I managed it by creating a file `/nginx/vhost.d/[vhost-name]_location` in my project-folder, mount this folder as volume to the proxy with the `docker-compose.yml` and added the beforementioned line to it. This file is then picked up by the proxy once it is started with docker-compose

See [jwilder-nginx Documentation](https://github.com/nginx-proxy/nginx-proxy#per-virtual_host-location-configuration) and [nginx-documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html) for more information.